# How to enable wps.Login and wps.SelfCare

Tags: websphere-portal

I want to show login and registration links on portal site , I got some info on this from some sites that you need to enable **wps.login** and **wps.selfcare** but didn't found how to enable these.

What is the way to enable these?

Thanks,
Pranav

Answer (score 0):

**wps.login** and **wps.selfcare** should be referring to specific Portal pages. Login as an Administration and go to "Manage Pages". You can search for pages by uniquename and find them. Make sure they have a status of "Active". If they are "Inactive" click the status to activate them.